# React Cannot read property 'name' of undefined on object that is defined?

Tags: reactjs, mern

I keep getting error  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` It is referring to the end of the code there when I am trying to reference .name on the subdivisions object. What I think is happening is it is trying to reference it before the page is actually loaded. It was working all the way up until I started trying to make that call to get the cities subdivisions. If someone can tell me what I am doing wrong in setting subdivision state to false before actually trying to access it. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link, navigate } from "@reach/router";

const SubdivisionDetails = (props) => {
    const [subdivision, setSubdivision] = useState(false);

    const getSubdivision = () => {
        axios
            .get("http://localhost:8000/api/subdivisions/" + props.id)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                setSubdivision(res.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log("Error: ", err));
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getSubdivision();
    }, [props.id]);

    const { removeSubdivisionFromDom } = props;

    return (
        <div className="mt-5 container">
            <div className="row justify-content-center mb-3">
                <h2>
                    {subdivision ? subdivision.name : ""} -
                    {subdivision ? subdivision.city.name : ""}
                </h2>
            </div>
```

Comment: Sounds like the `.city` property does not exist

Comment: @CertainPerformance it does exist, I can see it in postman when i test the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would set `subdivision` to an empty object instead of false for its initial state as that is the type that the data will be returning.

Secondly, I would use optional chaining which checks that the object data is there before carrying on in the object chain and therefor doesn't return an error if it's not there and just returns undefined.

That would make your return statement look like this:

```
 {subdivision?.name} - {subdivision?.city?.name}
```

Note the `?.` before each new object variable.

I have almost changed the ternary operator to the logical `&&` operator as you don't have an else condition.

Comment: That was it, before i had the question mark after subdivision but not after city. So when chaining them it needs a questionmark after each property? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: just code this: {subdivision?.name} - {subdivision?.city?.name}

Comment: @YuMiao you're so right! I got too hung up on the original code.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you rely on the data fetched from an API call to server to populate your view, it's a good practice to guard against the cases whence your API returns null/empty values.

Here in this scenarios, you can use two guards to make sure the `subDivision`(use camelCase naming) state is actually present.

1. Add a `Loader` component/logic to showing a loading view until the whole data is fetched from server. Example:

```js
    // previous code as is
    useEffect(() => {
        getSubdivision();
    }, [props.id]);

    const { removeSubdivisionFromDom } = props;

    if (!subdivisions || subdivisions === {}) { // ----> Guard against null/empty values
      return (
         <p>Loading...</p>
      )
    }

    return (
        <div className="mt-5 container">
            <div className="row justify-content-center mb-3">
                <h2>
                    {subdivision ? subdivision.name : ""} -
                    {subdivision ? subdivision.city.name : ""}
                </h2>
            </div>
   )
}
```

2. Always make sure you optionally chain(using the `?` operator) when trying to access nested objects/keys. Example:

```
 return (
        <div className="mt-5 container">
            <div className="row justify-content-center mb-3">
                <h2>
                    {subdivision?.name || ""} -
                    {subdivision?.city?.name || ""}
                </h2>
            </div>
   )
```

Please go through these references to understand more clearly the points I have elaborated:

[How to handle AJAX requests - Official React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)

[Why use guard clauses?](https://betterprogramming.pub/refactoring-guard-clauses-2ceeaa1a9da)